# Detonation and deflagration

Tags: explosives

I understand that deflagration is slower and smoother than a detonation, but can't a deflagration be used to initiate detonations of other explosive agents?

Comment: I don't know enough about combustion dynamics to give a good answer, but the Google search seems to indicate "Yes": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflagration_to_detonation_transition

Comment: This article may be of interest http://shepherd.caltech.edu/EDL/publications/reprints/jannaf99_paper.pdf